# how to send jms reply in an enterprise java applications

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, netbeans-7, glassfish-4

HI guys I have to develop an application where i have to build a bridge between two enterprise application and I am using JMS to establish the communication between these two application. Here I am using Message Driven Bean to send the JMS message from one application to another. I am struck where when my one application can send the message to other one but can not send the reply back to the requestor one.

```
private void sendJMSMessageToMyTestQueue(Message messageData) {
    try {
        context.createProducer().send(myTestQueue, messageData);
        System.out.println("\tTime:       " + System.currentTimeMillis() + " ms");
        System.out.println("\tMessage ID: " + messageData.getJMSMessageID());
        System.out.println("\tCorrel. ID: " + messageData.getJMSCorrelationID());
        System.out.println("\tReply to:   " + messageData.getJMSReplyTo());
        //System.out.println("\tContents:   " + messageData.getText());
    } catch (JMSException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HomeLoanJMS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}



private void recieveSync() {

    Message msg = context.createConsumer(myTestQueue).receive();
    if (msg instanceof TextMessage) {
        try {
            TextMessage tms = (TextMessage) msg;
            System.out.println("Received reply ");
            System.out.println("Received reply ");
            System.out.println("\tTime:       " + System.currentTimeMillis() + " ms");
            System.out.println("\tMessage ID: " + tms.getJMSMessageID());
            System.out.println("\tCorrel. ID: " + tms.getJMSCorrelationID());
            System.out.println("\tReply to:   " + tms.getJMSReplyTo());
            System.out.println("\tContents:   " + tms.getText());
            System.out.println("Coming Reply:  ---->>>>" + tms.getText());

        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HomeLoanJMS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void sendMessage(String message) {
    try {
        TextMessage msg = context.createTextMessage(message);
        // msg.setJMSType("Textmsg");
        msg.setText(message);
        msg.setJMSReplyTo(myTestQueue); //setting reply destination
        sendJMSMessageToMyTestQueue(msg);
        System.out.println("after reply");
     //   recieveSync();
    } catch (JMSException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HomeLoanJMS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

But when this message is received by the replier I does print the getReplyTo destination but when i build a reply and send it back it set the destination value as null and reply is never executed. the replier code is given below

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = { 
      @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
    , @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "jms/myTestQueue")
}) 
public class TestingMDB implements MessageListener {
    @EJB
    private SavingBeanRemote savingBean;
    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/myTestQueue")
    private Queue myTestQueue;
    @Inject
    @JMSConnectionFactory("jms/myTestQueueConnectionFactory")
    private JMSContext context;

    public TestingMDB() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            if (message instanceof MapMessage) {
                MapMessage mmsg = (MapMessage) message;
                String id = mmsg.getString("messageType");
                System.out.println(id);
                String cid = mmsg.getString("C_ID");
                System.out.println(cid);

            } else if (message instanceof TextMessage && (message.getJMSReplyTo() != null)) {
                TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) message;
                System.out.println("Received request");
                System.out.println("\tTime:       " + System.currentTimeMillis() + " ms");
                System.out.println("\tMessage ID: " + tm.getJMSMessageID());
                System.out.println("\tCorrel. ID: " + tm.getJMSCorrelationID());
                System.out.println("\tReply to:   " + tm.getJMSReplyTo());
                System.out.println("\tContents:   " + tm.getText());
                String contents = tm.getText();

                Double balance = savingBean.getBalance("c0566664", "a4016692");
                String text = (String)balance.toString();
                Destination replyDestination = (Destination)message.getJMSReplyTo();

                TextMessage replyMessage = context.createTextMessage();
                replyMessage.setText(text);
                replyMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(tm.getJMSMessageID());
                context.createProducer().send(replyDestination, replyMessage);
                System.out.println("Sent reply");
                System.out.println("\tTime:       " + System.currentTimeMillis() + " ms");
                System.out.println("\tMessage ID: " + replyMessage.getJMSMessageID());
                System.out.println("\tCorrel. ID: " + replyMessage.getJMSCorrelationID());
                System.out.println("\tReply to:   " + replyMessage.getJMSReplyTo());
                System.out.println("\tContents:   " + replyMessage.getText());
                TextMessage tms = context.createTextMessage("Reply from Client");

                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    try {
                        try {
                            System.out.println(message.equals(tm));

                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            System.out.println(tm.getText());
                            System.out.println(tm.getText());

                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(TestingMDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }

                    } catch (JMSException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(TestingMDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

                }

            } else {
                System.out.println("error");
            }
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestingMDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

so what is happening that i can send a message but can not receive the reply. please help me what am i missing or doing wrong. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the same queue (`myTestQueue`) both for the request message and the reply message.  This is bad because, you're receiver might be receiving the reply message instead of the sender/requestor.

In general, when doing request/reply with JMS, using `javax.jms.QueueRequestor` should be better than doing a "manual" implementation with sending the request message followed by trying to receive it.